Laravel Jetstream | Two Factor Authentication - GAuth code is rejected
I've installed Laravel 11 with Jetstream (Livewire).
I enabled 2FA and I scanned the QR code with Google-Authenticator, then I get the code on my smartphone, but when I type it on the page, I get:
The provided two factor authentication code was invalid.


Tried few other codes, and pasting the Setup Key instead of scanning the QR. Same result.
Then I deleted two_factor_secret from users table, and tried again with GAuth. Same result, the code provided is rejected. No errors in laravel.log and I'm able to login without 2FA.
What else should check? How do I Reset Jetstream? Thanks

I found the solution below. The problem was with the time on my VPS, just few seconds out of sync with the time on my laptop and smartphone. Thanks
Check the time and date on your phone and make sure they match the computer or device you are logging in from.
https://help.artsy.net/s/article/My-two-factor-authentication-codes-are-not-working-what-do-I-do#:~:text=Authenticator%20apps%20rely%20on%20the,you%20are%20logging%20in%20from.
